# Move workspace to different stream in Accurev CLI

Tags: accurev

Accurev CLI documentation does not mention any command to move workspace from one stream to another without the need of creating a new workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Look in manual at the "accurev chws" command

Try running this command:

- accurev chws -w "workspace name" -b "name of new backing stream"

Once complete, you will need to update your workspace:

- accurev update